# How can I check actual functionalities of the API and how can I configure API with my website

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I have API key and network id which is running on [Hasoffer](http://developers.hasoffers.com/#/affiliate) platform and provided by my [Vcommisson.com](http://vcommission.com) (My affiliate company)

Please tell me how can I check actual functionalities of the API. Actually I wanted to update coupons and deals automatically on my website with help of API of vcommission. How can I configure API with my website which is under development on wordpress platform.

Please help me and if possible then please share any images in the answer.

Comment: Did you read the API documentation?

Comment: http://developers.hasoffers.com/#/affiliate All methods are listed there.

Comment: i have read but i didn't understand about the API has feature for  automatically updation .... could you please find that feature details on hasoffers link and please let me know PLease please

Answer (score 0):

```
1 open chrome browser. 
2 install apps    (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/rest%20client?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) 
3 open this apps and use
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Bhavesh,Thaks for your response but please explain bit briefly what i need to put in this app ..... Please help me i am not a developer so i need more information about these image process

Comment: My answer in 3 images and second image is image upload in you API

Comment: you have file name like ex "img_upload", file name is pass the request variable like ex: $_FILES['img_upload']; $_FILES is request variable.
make a PUT request that includes a file with name field set to "fileUpload", look my second image i pass the "logo" and "banner" it is my image file name and your file name is ex: img_upload so you pass your image file name "img_upload" and look my second image chooes file so select your file and click send button

Comment: check this link this is my blog site https://valabhavesh.wordpress.com/2015/07/01/73/